# ionic 3 move from login page to Tabspage gives error

Tags: ionic-framework, authentication, ionic3

i'm trying to make an app that has login page then after login the user must be insde tabs page, i get error

app.components.ts

```
import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';

    @Component({
      templateUrl: 'app.html'
    })
    export class MyApp {
      rootPage:any = LoginPage;

      constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
        platform.ready().then(() => {
          // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
          // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
          statusBar.styleDefault();
          splashScreen.hide();
        });
      }
    }
```

login.ts

```
 signIn(){
 this.navCtrl.push(TabsPage);
 }
```

login.html

```
   <button ion-button  block (click)="signIn()">Sign In</button>
```

when i click sign in button i get the below error, please help

```
Runtime Error
Uncaught (in promise): invalid views to insert
Stack
Error: Uncaught (in promise): invalid views to insert
    at c (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:19752)
    at Object.reject (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:19174)
    at NavControllerBase._fireError (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:51705:16)
    at NavControllerBase._failed (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:51698:14)
    at http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:51745:59
    at t.invoke (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:14976)
    at Object.onInvoke (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:5134:33)
    at t.invoke (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:14916)
    at r.run (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10143)
    at http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:20242
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found it write, i didn't not import TabsPage, after import it was working well